# Using multiple tableViews?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to use two tableCells on top of each other and then hiding one when the other needs to be used. So far I have everything working pretty good, however the constraints seem to be causing a fuss, and I cannot figure it out.

I used the auto layout features, but I can't understand why there is so much padding on the "Sweet" section.

[image: This is the first view.]

[image: This is the second view.]

Comment: Please provide more screenshots. Impossible to say with only these two screenshots

Comment: I'm about 90% sure that you added auto layout constraints differently for the "sweet" tableview and the "sour" tableview.. check the top space constraint for both tables and make sure they are the same

Comment: And I recommend you to use two different arrays for holding contents for "Sweet" & "Sour"
And in cell for row at index path datasource method switch the array based on segment.selectedSegmentIndex
And On segmentValueChanged: method perform tableView.reloadData.
This is the most recommended way for approaching the above task

Answer (score 0):

- This may be an issue due to section height,
- Try setting section header & tableView header height to 0 using its delegate method or through storyboard(Select the tableView -> In File Inspector -> Set header value to 0).
- I hope this would fix your issue.